# Identify author by a text's grammatical/syntactic structure

Tags: computational-linguistics, stylometry

I'm interested in whether it is possible to classify texts by authorship using just syntactic/grammatical information.

Let's take ten people and have them write three texts. About their favorite hobby, a political commentary and the third one is a fictional story. 
For the classification I do not want to use information like vocabulary or typos but just the grammatical role of a word in a sentence.

Is it possible to turn such information into a vector f.x. and classify it?

**UPDATE**

As suggested by hippietrail I'll try to clarify further what aspect I am interested in.

Naturally one can quantify anything and then have a clustering or classification algorithm work on it.

> Basically you can use any metric you can think up beside just vocab, word frequency and typos. The latter won't even apply to identifying edited texts. Things like collocations, hyphenation, sentence length - anything imaginable. (hippietrail)

(hyphenation f.x. does not interest me for the purposes of this question - only the grammatical level.)

But I am not a linguist and I wouldn't want to start from scratch guessing my way to a useful quantification. So I am wondering whether there is already a quantification/vectorization of the above mentioned grammatical information distilled from a text that is known to serve this purpose of authorship identification sufficiently well. Maybe even a "classical" approach.

Comment: This is fun stuff but it isn't really linguistics and it's definitely not natural language processing. But I would say it probably *is* computational linguistics, so that would mean it's on topic anyway (-:

Comment: Well a major part of the problem is to turn a text into a representation on a grammatical level. This would need technology from the area of NLP. But my question is primarily addressing the part after this transformation. But I think it belongs also to "classical" linguistics - or maybe psycho(logical) linguistics, as the core question is whether texts show individual (or at least group-specific) grammatical patterns.

Comment: To my knowledge you actually don't try to parse the text to do this. It's an unnecessary, expensive, and inherently ambiguoug task. You analyze stylistic things. I'm not sure if it has a more usual name than "author identification". I think it does but it's not coming to me.

Comment: Wikipedia: **[Stylometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylometry)** is often used to attribute authorship to anonymous or disputed documents. It has legal as well as academic and literary applications, ranging from the question of the authorship of Shakespeare's works to forensic linguistics.

Comment: Good point. One reason why placed this (hypothetical) transformation at the beginning is because I intended to forestall answers referring to vocabulary, word frequency or typos. Yet, a labelling would be necessary - left undecided whether this process occures separate and preparational or is seemlessly integrated into the identification and encoding of patterns.

Comment: "Stylometry" - nice one! Now I can already google it ;)

Comment: Yes after answering I wondered if you specifically wanted to know about syntax-tree-based stylometry. I'm not sure if such a thing has been done but it would be very interesting and that would also warrant the NLP tag, and be more "linguistically". Please edit it into your question to be more explicit if that's what you're most interested in. Basically you can use any metric you can think up beside just vocab, word frequency and typos. The latter won't even apply to identifying edited texts. Things like collocations, hyphenation, sentence length - anything imaginable.

Comment: You could also get away with just tagging rather than fully parsing to get the "grammatical roles". It won't be totally accurate but neither will parsing.

Comment: I believe the main keyword in NLP is "author attribution" or "authorship attribution", and it's an area of active and vibrant research. Here's a relevant [Google search query](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22author+attribution%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=ib1OUs-pIojMhAeNxYBQ#q=%22author+attribution%22+nlp&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&safe=off) that provides many useful links like [this survey](http://www.icsd.aegean.gr/lecturers/stamatatos/papers/survey.pdf) of the field and current methods.

Comment: You say hyphenation is not present on a grammatical level - so this suggests that you already have this grammatical breakdown. If you don't already have it and your task is author ID then you want to use everything at hand. Now if your question is just that those bits are not what you want to learn about that's also fine. But to say hyphenation won't be available is just wrong. Even a full parse is quite capable of retaining this kind of information. It's just like an AST of a computer program retaining line numbers.

Comment: my question is referring to grammatical information and structures only. it's not just a practical question.

Comment: OK I clarified it a bit. The term "structure" has special meanings in the context of text analysis which have nothing to do with grammatical structure / syntax etc. @robert is right - there's not a "classical" solution to this - it's an area of active research with different people taking different approaches. There will be many ways to vectorize - probably each person thinks up a new one or builds on what they were able to find.

Comment: Executive summary: Stylometry works for some writers and not for others. In any event, it requires a **lot** of verified data from all authors concerned, and depends crucially on their idiosyncratic habits (which may include syntax in some cases, so parsing is not out of the question altogether), if they have any the software can recognize. Not ready for prime time, but certainly question-begging enough for the witness box.

Comment: I personally think this is very interesting. You could see things such as which verbs favour passives, grammatical roles of verbs, basically anything that can be expressed in two or more syntactic "constructions" could potentially reveal an "author style". I believe each such thing would become a "dimension", then there's standard ways of dimension reduction to see which ones turn out to be relevant, leaving you with metrics that can be compared in a sum-of-squares type manner. Vectors has always been my weak point so I'm sure if this is a different way of saying the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the links I'll provide are in German, but they seem to apply perfectly to your question:

- [Linguistic differential analysis and author identification](http://www.security-informatics.de/blog/?p=318)
- [History of computer-aided author identification](http://www.security-informatics.de/blog/?p=921)
- [Text classification and author identification using complex n-grams](http://www.security-informatics.de/blog/?p=250)
- [All articles](http://www.security-informatics.de/blog/?cat=22)

#### Linguistic differential analysis and author identification

The first article describes the use of a vector model. A message board is used as testing ground for author identification based on usage of certain vocabulary and word frequency.

For example, the third variable corresponds loosely to:

> "kriminell" -> "criminal"
>   "auf der schiefen Bahn" -> "not on the right track"
>   "straffällig" -> "has been convicted"

#### History of computer-aided author identification

A little context: The [militante gruppe (mg)](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Militante_gruppe_%28mg%29) was a radical left group that carried out small attacks on property in the early 2000s. Andrej Holm, a sociologist specializing in gentrification and similar topics, was detained by the police on the basis that he was part of the (mg). Authorship identification techniques were used to identify him.

The author first tries to group texts based on function words and concludes that it isn't a suitable metric for authorship identification. [This article](http://www.dh2012.uni-hamburg.de/conference/programme/abstracts/characterizing-authorship-style-using-linguistic-features/) disagrees with that conclusion.

The author then tries to use [complex n-gram models](http://www.security-informatics.de/blog/?p=250). This type of procedure is great for identifying the type of text (e.g., fiction, blog post, scientific journal) but isn't suitable for author identification.

Lastly, there is machine learning using various metrics (e.g., average sentence length, relative frequency of intensifying particles, relative frequency of passive voice).

The resulting decision tree is shown here:

[image: Decision tree]

One criticism is that shallow nodes have a higher chance of being wrongly classified, and that this method, again, identifies the type of text rather than the author.

One could argue that all these methods have shortcomings in not having enough data or classifiers. There are various other methods, e.g., [local histograms](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P11-1030), character n-grams (which supposedly works really well), and [Latent Semantic Indexing](https://engineering.purdue.edu/purpl/level2/papers/soboroff97visualizing.pdf).

Comment: In general, your paragraphs suffer from a lack of introductory and transitional sentences.    

1.    Please explain what your links pertain to in initial topic sentence.

2.  Expand your first example to, e.g., “Bear in mind that the German links contain German cultural references, for example, a reference to the newspaper column, Post von Wagner.”   

4.    Omit “so let’s start with that.” 

5. Re:   The History of... link.    You need to explain the relevance of the historical information.    The latter seems to be a puzzling abrupt topic change.

Comment: Also, please learn the markdown syntax so that you can post better links.